# How to get only argument value from prototype function

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, cucumber

Below is my constructor function "Req" and prototype function "get" to make http request.

```html
var request = require('request');

function Req(url, type, body) {
 this.url = url;
 this.username = "##############";
 this.password = "##############";
 this.type = type;
 this.body = body
 this.authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(this.username + ":" + this.password).toString("base64");
}


Req.prototype.get = function (callback) {

 request(
  {
   url: this.url,
   headers: { "Authorization": this.authenticationHeader }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
   if (error) {
    console.log("Error in Get Request is " + error)
   }
   else if (body) {
      console.log("******************GET Response is****************" + "\n" + body)
   }

   callback();
  }
 );
}
```

This is working fine and I am calling this prototype function like this in Cucumber

```html
var testObject;

Given('I have request with {string}, {string} and {string}', function (url, type, body) {
 testObject = new Req(url, type, body)


});
When('the request is triggered', function (callback) {
  testObject.get(callback);
})
```

But I want to show only response value that is "Body" within Then Step

```html
Then('I should get the result', function () {
 How to do here??
});
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `error` and `body` values to your callback so it can see those values.

```
Req.prototype.get = function(callback) {
    request({
            url: this.url,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": this.authenticationHeader
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error in Get Request is " + error)
                callback(error);
            } else {
                console.log("******************GET Response is****************" + "\n" + body)
                callback(null, body);
            } 
        }
    );
}

someObj.get(function(err, body) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

FYI, I don't know about protractor and cucumber so I've shown you a pure Javascript way to do this.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, it's working within "When" scope but not in "Then", thanks for your time on this.